# How to curl specific files through command line?

Tags: curl, command-line-interface

I have grep installed and trying to output certain matching criteria through an xml file nested with multiple child XML files. By using the below command

```
curl https://www.example.com/directory/directory.xml | grep -o  '\([a-z]\+-fr-FR_\(\d\)\+\.xml<\/loc>\)'
```

but it doesn't return the expected output as below:

```
<loc>https://www.example.com/directory/xxx-fr-fr_1.xml</loc>
<loc>https://www.example.com/directory/xxx-fr-fr_2.xml</loc>
```

Not sure if it's the regex not good enough or the way I have installed grep on my windows machine.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not sure why you have `/directory/directory.xml` in your curl url...as far as I can see, there is only the high level `https://www.example.com` domain and no subdomains or further paths below it. Also, I see no mention of xml files at all in that domain's page source so it would make sense that there is no match on your grep.

Comment: That's just an example URL and I do have hundreds of child xmls sitting on that domain. Let's say it looks like this: https://www.ebay.com/lst/PRP-0-index.xml So i thought of starting it from the same point. If i do a simple curl https://www.ebay.com/lst/PRP-0-index.xml it outputs all childs but I wish to only check for a specific pattern.

Comment: If you use `grep -o '\([a-z]\+-fr-fr_\(\d\)\+\.xml<\/loc>\)'` it will match on some of the output you listed (in particular it will show `xxx-fr-fr_1.xml</loc>`)